# Backbone: list all events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to ascertain whether or not events are getting unbound properly in a Backbone application.

To clarify, I'm referring to events that have been added in two ways:

1. From the view's `events` object:

   `events: { 'click #id': 'someFunction' }`
2. From `listenTo` or `on` calls:

   `this.listenTo(model, 'change', function () { // });`

How can output all such events to the console so that I can see if they're being removed when the view changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The events from  the view's `events` hash can be accessed via

```
myViewInstance.events
```

2) The objects from `listenTo` events (first argument) are stored in the view's `_listeners` property

```
myViewInstance._listeners
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug your Backbone app, try this extension for Chrome Developer Tools: https://github.com/Maluen/Backbone-Debugger.

It displays in real-time all the application views, models, collections and routers, with detailed information such as handled jQuery events, model attributes, collection models, sync status, events triggered and more.